# Glass Fish Connection Refused

Tags: java, glassfish

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:143)
        at com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientPipe.process(XWSSClientPipe.java:160)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
```

Error occurs when try to access web service  via Glassfish. When I use Jboss I can connect to web service

Comment: can you check for port no? are you able to access WSDL from your browser ?

Comment: Yes I can access wsdl from browser

Comment: then your client must.. there might be some url issue with client ,

Comment: Can you show the code as it might help?

Answer (score 0):

Your client library is connecting to other ip/host what you expect. Your ws client library was not build  against the same webservice host (i'm 99% sure). Just proper configure your application to connect to the right host and port and should work.

Here is a very simple example:   http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/glassfish/GFandMySQL_Part3.html

Just modify @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation="http://localhost:8080/helloservice/hello?wsdl") to your right location and should work.

Regards

Comment: But when I run the same application in the JBoss server it works. without any error.

Comment: I think is expecting other paths to find the configuration files.